# Most robust way to store api keys (client side)?

Tags: java, deployment, api-key, secret-key

I have created a java daemon program that collects data from social network accounts. I use a lot of services including Flick, S3, GeoCoding, etc. Currently I have the program set up to read all these API keys from a properties file. I also have a similarly formatted properties file in my test folder that contains different keys for testing purposes. These property files are not committed to source obviously. This collection program writes to a mongo db. I am also building a web app that also works with mongo and will be deployed along side the collection.  During my development I am reading that it is best to store keys as environment variables on the production side. It got me think; which leads me to my question...

I am wondering if there is a better way to handle these keys in my java program (from a deployment standpoint) or some possible routes that people have tried in doing something similar to this. Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a database. If you are only storing API keys for personal use, then the size of the database isn't probably a major concern. Personally, I would suggest MySQL (or alternatively SQLite) as they are both quite well-supported.

If you encrypt your keys then it shouldn't matter too much where you store your database, although of course I still wouldn't make it openly downloadable. Just pick a good encryption tool and *do not try developing your own encryption algorithm!*

Answer (score 0):

The latest hotness (in a world of containers) is to use [zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/), [etcd](https://coreos.com/etcd/) or [consul](https://www.consul.io/) as a distributed configuration store. The [confd](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd/blob/master/docs/quick-start-guide.md) tool is capable of ensuring that application configuration files are kept in sync with changes to configuration.

My personal preference is Consul which has a similar template tool called [consul-template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template), and another called [envconsul](https://github.com/hashicorp/envconsul) if you would prefer your program to consume environment variables.

Finally Hasicorp, the makers of consul, have an encryption product called [vault](https://vaultproject.io/). It works well with consul and is also supported by [consul-template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template).