# What is a clever way to hide an access key?

Tags: android

In my android app, I am using an external api with my own secret access key. To use functions from the api, I must call a function with a String representing my secret access key. Problem is, everybody can see this (by decompiling the apk).

- I can't use proguard

What is a clever way to hide my secret access key?

Comment: Voted to close, because it's a question inviting opinion. The usual suspects apply, from steganography to encryption. Or store it in the cloud and load it upon install and check periodically. This way you can change it, too.

Comment: Check Android Key Strore, it could help you: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html. I agree this question seems that you are asking about opinions. There are plenty of similar topics in SO: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358185/most-robust-way-to-store-api-keys-client-side
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134031/is-there-a-safe-way-to-manage-api-keys
You can always have private/public key keep them in android store and exchange if needed.